# Can't use Polygon to Clip Raster

Tags: gdal, clip, gdalwarp

I created a polygon to use to clip a DTM raster (DEMTiff), but the Clip by Mask tool gives an error:

GDAL command:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -of GTiff -cutline temp.shp -cl temp -crop_to_cutline "D:\\Nadar-Working\\Saxon Vista Circle\\SaxonVistaCanyon_1_DTM_final.tif" C:/Users/jeffc/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_VIkBPI/f414aad4007c4625bff642291be5ac6c/OUTPUT.tif
```

GDAL command output:

> ERROR 1: Did not get any cutline features.
>
> Process returned error code 1

Comment: Have you tried providing the full path to `temp.shp`?

Comment: Does ogrinfo list at least one polygon with `ogrinfo temp.shp -al`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the coordinate reference system (CRS) is the same for both the vector data and the raster data.  [Here is a link](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) on warping your raster data to comply with your vector data.  You can use `gdalinfo yourfilehere` or similarly `ogrinfo yourfilehere` to display and confirm the CRS of these data.